# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Jan 19 2012 08:00 PM"

Tags: java, date, timestamp

I would like to parse a date. My String date is "Thu Jan 19 2012 08:00 PM". And my code to parse is:

```
format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy hh:mm aaa");
this.settDate(new Timestamp((format.parse(sDate)).getTime()));
```

However, it does not work. How could I parse this date?

Complete method is:

```
public void saveTask(int iDevice, String description, String sDate) throws ParseException {
    format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy hh:mm aaa");
    this.setiDeviceId(iDevice);
    this.setsDescription(description);
    this.settDate(new Timestamp((format.parse(sDate)).getTime()));
    DatabaseManager.save(this);
}
```

And exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Jan 19 2012 01:00 AM"
```

Debug picture:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy hh:mm a");`

Comment: your code works fine for me. Show more code.

Comment: your format is fine, works for me, i get : `Thu Jan 19 20:00:00 SAST 2012` what is your error, how does it not 'work'?

Comment: Yes, I do so. But it does not work either.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try below code... Tested and worked

```
    String dateStr = "Thu Jan 19 2012 01:00 PM";
    DateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "EEE MMM dd yyyy hh:mm aaa");

    DateFormat writeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = null;
    try {
       date = readFormat.parse( dateStr );
    } catch ( ParseException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String formattedDate = "";
    if( date != null ) {
    formattedDate = writeFormat.format( date );
    }

    System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Output is `2012-01-19 13:00:00`

Cheers!!! Happy to help!!!

Answer (score 5):

Try setting a Locale such as US in this case:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy hh:mm aaa",Locale.US);
format.parse("Thu Jan 19 2012 08:00 PM");
```

Answer (score 3):

What is your default locale? Since the date string is in English, try parsing it with the US locale:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.US);
```

Comment: @Andrey Yes, but Jose Hdez's default locale is probably not US or UK, so he gets an error if he doesn't specify which locale should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that value really got to that call. Put a breakpoint right on that line and double check actual value.

As you can see here http://ideone.com/MBzYn code works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

// make sure your string date and DateFormat pattern are same;
                                // for example you have String date="2018/07/10 10:00:00";

```
                            DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

                            // now makesure format has same pattern in this case ""yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
```