# Android date to string conversion issue

Tags: android, string, parsing, datetime-format

I want to convert : Wed Apr 06 09:37:00 GMT+03:00 2016 to 02/02/2012.
What i tried

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
    Date date = sdf.parse(mydate);
```

and

```
 String mydate =  "Wed Apr 06 09:37:00 GMT+03:00 2016";
            SimpleDateFormat src = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
            SimpleDateFormat dest = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = src.parse(mydate);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.d("deneme",e.getMessage());
            }
            String result = dest.format(date);
```

but its give error Unparseable date: "Wed Apr 06 09:37:00 GMT+03:00 2016" (at offset 0) any idea how i can parse it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911099/java-text-parseexception-unparseable-date-thu-jan-19-2012-0800-pm

Comment: @keikoman take my code and put it direct it will give you the result

Comment: @Kelkoman     you convert your date to miliseconds and then parse them to your desired format

Comment: [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to format an english locale date but your system locale is not english. So when you create the `SimpleDateFormat` object specify the `Locale` explicity.

Try this code,

```
    String mydate = "Wed Apr 06 09:37:00 GMT+03:00 2016";
    SimpleDateFormat src = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    SimpleDateFormat dest = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = src.parse(mydate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.d("Exception",e.getMessage());
    }
    String result = dest.format(date);
    Log.d("result", result);
```

Comment: **For future visitors**: The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67389571/10819573) answers, one should be able to solve it with `java.time` API.