# Java date format convertion

Tags: java, android, mysql, date, date-conversion

In my android app i need to convert a date from 'Jan 2017,20' this format to '19-1-2017'.The date is selected from the Date Picker in '19-1-2017' format and stored in MySQL db as 'Jan 2017,20'.When i take the date value from database i need to convert the date 'Jan 2017,20' format back to '19-1-2017'.
is there any way to do this?
thanks in advance.
please help.

**datepicker code**

```
edit_meeting_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        final Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog=new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int monthofYear, int dayofMonth) {
                System.out.println("dayofMonth :"+dayofMonth+"\nmonthofYear : "+(monthofYear+1)+"\nyear : "+year);
                edit_meeting_date.setText(dayofMonth+"-"+(monthofYear+1)+"-"+year);
             }
         },mYear,mMonth,mDay);
         datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
         datePickerDialog.show();
     }
});
```

Comment: See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056703/simpledateformat-ignoring-month-when-parsing/38217721#38217721

Comment: You should be displaying dates to the users preference not to a program specification

Comment: Thanks guys for the replys.
i got the answer .
[Answer link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911099/java-text-parseexception-unparseable-date-thu-jan-19-2012-0800-pm)

Answer (score 1):

You can make the function convertDate and can play with any type of Date Format.

```html
 public static String ConvertDate(String current_format, String date, String new_format) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf_current = new SimpleDateFormat(current_format);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf_new = new SimpleDateFormat(new_format);
            Date get_date = sdf_current.parse(date);
            return sdf_new.format(get_date);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Error:" + e.getMessage();
        }

    }
```

**Example:**

```html
ConvertDate("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss","Jan 10 2017 20:20:20","MMM dd yyyy");
```

Comment: This is a classic utility method that should be in every developer's toolkit

Answer (score 0):

Use **SimpleDateFormat**

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
Date formattedDate = formatter.parse(dateFromDb);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format a java date using a SimpleDateFormatter:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String formattedDate = formatter.format(theDate);
```